# C Programming: What conditions do I put for an if statements for numbers 1 to 35 inclusive?

Tags: c, integer, conditional-statements, verify

Okay I need help with translating sentences to condition statements in C.
For example, if I want my input to be from 1 to 35 (inclusive), and only want odd integer inputs, how would I go about making a conditional statements?
Is it:

```
int n;
    while(1){
        printf("What is the value for n you wish to use (please use an odd number?: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n%2=0 && n<=35 && n>=1)
            if(n<1)
            break;  
        }
```

Comment: `if(n%2==1 && n<=35 && n>=1) break;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (n%2=0 && n<=35 && n>=1)
```

is (almost) the condition for even numbers, those exactly divisible by 2.  Note that the equality operator is `==`.  For odd, you want

```
    if (n%2==1 && n<=35 && n>=1)
```

With this, you do not need any more `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

This `n%2=0` should be (for odd numbers) `n%2 == 1`

And if you want to break on a number not matching your conditions, use something like this in the loop:

```
if(!((n%2 == 1) && (n<=35) && (n>=1)))
    break;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now if you want to break from a loops if any one of following condition get satisfies

1. The number must be above 1
2. The number must be below 35
3. The number must be odd

Then you can write:

```
if(n%2==1 || n>=35 || n<=1) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define the tests for 1 to 35 inclusive. C supports short circuiting, we should test the simple things -

```
if (n > 0 && n < 36) /* <---- 1 to 35 */
if (n >= 1 && n <= 35) /* <---- 1 to 35 */
```

or

```
#define MIN 1
#define MAX 35
if (n >= MIN && n <= MAX) /* MIN to MAX */
```

However, your code is incorrect. The second `if` will ever evaluate to true since the first requires `n>=1`

```
if(n%2=0 && n<=35 && n>=1)
  if(n<1)
    break;
```

I believe you wanted

```
if (n > 35 || n < 1) {
  break;
}
```

A test for even should just continue (and not end the loop), or you could test for odd and just display those,

```
if (n % 2 == 0) continue;
```

or

```
if (n % 2 != 0) printf("%i\n", n);
```